# Return average apple object

Tags: java

So i'll try to explain this. I have a list, appleList, which has apple objects in it. Each customer object has a username and a list of products i I'm struggling to get the length of the my apples. If I could do that then I could save them to a variable and divide by the amount. I'm just stuck. Any input would be great!

```
public double applelength(){
    for(int i=0; i<applelist.length(); i++)
}
```

Comment: `customerList.stream().mapToDouble(c -> c.getWishList().size()).average()`.

Comment: hmm but is there a way to do it without maps?

Comment: That isn't using maps. It's a stream and a function

Comment: Sure. Just write the stream as a loop instead.

Comment: We can't see what object is in this list. We therefore don't know how you get the wishlist

Comment: I added the object method. And im lost on how to use a loop for this... i just don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm struggling to get the length of the wishlists

You  already know how to get the size of a list. You are struggling to get an item out of a list?

> this will go to each individual customer object

Not quite... It only counts the index. You still need to access the objects in the list

You simply  need to get the total items then divide. Here's an example using an enhanced for loop

```
double total = 0.0;
for (Customer c : customers)
    total += c.getWishlist().size();
double average = total / customers.size();
```

(This code will throw an exception if you have an empty list)

**Edit**

Your `getProducts()` doesn't compile, but that's not needed for this answer

Comment: when i compile i get an error with the total += c.getWishList().size() line. It says cannot find symbol and point to the "."

Comment: Obviously you need to use the correct method to actually get the wishlist. Like I said, we can't see your class

Comment: im starting to get it. I put my getProducts method in the question but im getting a compiler error with return customerList(n)  saying it can't find the symbol. Do you see where i went wrong there? I also really appreciate you helping me out with this!

Comment: That code just isn't syntactically correct. Maybe try something simpler? For example, when you return from the inside of a list, you immediately exit the loop. I honestly don't know what you're expecting there

Comment: i dont know how to go simpler though that the issue im lost as can be :(

Comment: My answer doesn't need a list of strings. You don't need to call `getProducts`. Please show your full Customer class

Comment: I added it for you

Comment: Okay, so you have `getWishlist()`, so what's the problem?

Comment: omg you sir are a hero! thank you so much! If i could direct you here to help this guy (who totally isnt me on a different account) that'd be awesome! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354307/add-product-p-to-customer-n-in-arraylist

Comment: Considering both questions start with "So, I try to explain this", I'd say it is also you. The link in the comments there is very good. So is reading what a [mcve] is, and more generally, https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking